# Syntax for date range SQL query in OpenOffice Base

Tags: sql, openoffice.org

I'm trying to SELECT based on a date in OpenOffice Base:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OrderTbl
  WHERE OrdDate BETWEEN #1/1/2007# AND #1/31/2007#
```

I've tried a number of variations, but nothing is working.  What is the correct syntax?

Comment: have you tried single quotes instead of #s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OrderTbl
WHERE OrdDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-01-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

use below Query
SELECT *
  FROM OrderTbl
  WHERE OrdDate BETWEEN cast(convert(varchar,'1/1/2007',101) as datetime) AND cast((varchar,'1/31/2007',101) as datetime)